# nvidia-docker: Unknown runtime specified nvidia

Tags: docker, nvidia-docker

I've looked up older answers on this which did not help ([#1](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52865988/nvidia-docker-unknown-runtime-specified-nvidia), [#2](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50364031/cant-execute-nvidia-runtime-on-docker))

I'm getting this error when trying to launch a docker-compose projcet with a container that has the `runtime: nvidia` flag.

Following the latest instructions, I installed docker (version 19.03) and the latest nvidia-docker per the [repository](https://github.com/NVIDIA/nvidia-docker) for Ubuntu.
I did not register the runtime anywhere, as the [documentation clearly states that it is not necessary now](https://github.com/nvidia/nvidia-container-runtime#docker-engine-setup).

Running a single container works, e.g. `docker run --gpus all nvidia/cuda:10.0-base nvidia-smi` this works perfectly - but when I try to launch the docker-compose project, it fails with the following error

> ERROR: for MY_SERVICE  Cannot create container for service MY_SERVICE: Unknown runtime specified nvidia

I don't know if it has anything to do with this, but I'm running on GCP Compute Engine, Ubuntu 18.04

Comment: I could run the [docker-compose example](https://github.com/NVIDIA/gpu-monitoring-tools/blob/master/exporters/prometheus-dcgm/docker/) in [nvidia-docker FAQ](https://github.com/NVIDIA/nvidia-docker/wiki/Frequently-Asked-Questions#do-you-support-docker-compose)
Could you try that docker-compose file to confirm it isn't you compose file? Or could you share an extract of your docker-compose? 
One detail, what doc says is that nvidia-docker2 doesn't requiere to manually configure the runtime, but that config has to be present in order to work.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The newest version of `nvidia-docker` does not have a docker-compose support yet. From a [discussion with a contributor](https://github.com/NVIDIA/nvidia-docker/issues/1073#issuecomment-532104398), it has made clear to me that in order to work with docker-compose one must change a specific step in the installation process to install the previous version of `nvidia-docker`, as said per the contributor:

> One the README (about installation)
>
> ```
> -L https://nvidia.github.io/nvidia-docker/gpgkey | sudo apt-key add - $ curl -s -L
> https://nvidia.github.io/nvidia-docker/$distribution/nvidia-docker.list
> | sudo tee /etc/apt/sources.list.d/nvidia-docker.list
>
> $ sudo apt-get update && sudo apt-get install -y
> nvidia-container-toolkit $ sudo systemctl restart docker
> ```
>
> Replace the line:
>
> ```
> nvidia-container-toolkit
> ```
>
> By:
>
> ```
> $ sudo apt-get update && sudo apt-get install -y nvidia-docker2
> ```