# Add nvidia runtime to docker runtimes

Tags: docker, cuda, gpu, nvidia-docker

I’m running a virtual vachine on `GCP` with a tesla GPU. 
And try to deploy a `PyTorch`-based app to accelerate it with GPU.

**I want to make docker use this GPU, have access to it from containers.**

I managed to install all drivers on host machine, and the app runs fine there, but when I try to run it in docker (based on nvidia/cuda container) pytorch fails:

```
File "/usr/local/lib/python3.6/dist-packages/torch/cuda/__init__.py", line 82, 
in _check_driver http://www.nvidia.com/Download/index.aspx""")
AssertionError: 
Found no NVIDIA driver on your system. Please check that you have an NVIDIA GPU and installed a driver from
```

To get some info about nvidia drivers visible to the container, I run this:

`docker run --runtime=nvidia --rm nvidia/cuda nvidia-smi`
But it complains: `docker: Error response from daemon: Unknown runtime specified nvidia.`

On the host machine `nvidia-smi` output looks like this:

```
+-----------------------------------------------------------------------------+
| NVIDIA-SMI 440.33.01    Driver Version: 440.33.01    CUDA Version: 10.2     |
|-------------------------------+----------------------+----------------------+
| GPU  Name        Persistence-M| Bus-Id        Disp.A | Volatile Uncorr. ECC |
| Fan  Temp  Perf  Pwr:Usage/Cap|         Memory-Usage | GPU-Util  Compute M. |
|===============================+======================+======================|
|   0  Tesla P100-PCIE...  On   | 00000000:00:04.0 Off |                    0 |
| N/A   39C    P0    35W / 250W |    873MiB / 16280MiB |      0%      Default |
+-------------------------------+----------------------+----------------------+
```

If I check my runtimes in docker, I get only `runc` runtime, no `nvidia` as in examples around the internet.

```
$ docker info|grep -i runtime
 Runtimes: runc
 Default Runtime: runc
```

**How can I add this `nvidia` runtime environment to my docker?**

Most posts and questions I found so far say something like "I just forgot to restart my docker daemon, it worked", but it does not help me. Whot should I do?

I checked many issues on github, and [#1](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/57957491/nvidia-docker-unknown-runtime-specified-nvidia), [#2](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52865988/nvidia-docker-unknown-runtime-specified-nvidia) and [#3](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50364031/cant-execute-nvidia-runtime-on-docker) StackOverflow questions - didn't help.

Comment: 1. Install latest driver for your NVIDIA GPU on the base system.  2. Install docker-ce **19.03** or newer.  3. launch your containers with `--gpus all` switch.  4. Profit!   See here: https://docs.nvidia.com/ngc/ngc-titan-setup-guide/index.html

Comment: To share some experience: Some older projects rely on the interface option, `--runtime nvidia`, of the deprecated nvidia-docker2. The checked answer (install nvidia-container-runtime and edit /etc/docker/daemon.json), can be installed on top of the new nvidia-docker-toolkit seems compatible with it and achieves the required backwards compatibility with just a very small package (600kB on Ubuntu).

Answer (score 26, accepted):

The `nvidia` runtime you need, is `nvidia-container-runtime`.

Follow the installation instructions here:
https://github.com/NVIDIA/nvidia-container-runtime#installation

Basically, you install it with your package manager first, if it's not present:

`sudo apt-get install nvidia-container-runtime`

Then you add it to docker runtimes:
https://github.com/nvidia/nvidia-container-runtime#daemon-configuration-file

This option worked for me:

```
$ sudo tee /etc/docker/daemon.json <<EOF
{
    "runtimes": {
        "nvidia": {
            "path": "/usr/bin/nvidia-container-runtime",
            "runtimeArgs": []
        }
    }
}
EOF
sudo pkill -SIGHUP dockerd
```

Check that it's added:

```
$ docker info|grep -i runtime
 Runtimes: nvidia runc
 Default Runtime: runc
```

Answer (score 2):

As an update to @Viacheslav Shalamov's answer, the `nvidia-container-runtime` package is now part of the `nvidia-container-toolkit` which can also be installed with:

```
sudo apt install nvidia-cuda-toolkit
```

and then follow the same instruction above to set `nvidia` as default runtime.