# Add fake nvidia runtime to docker runtimes

Tags: docker, docker-compose, nvidia-docker

How to create a fake `nvidia` runtime in my installation of docker, so I can run `docker-compose` files that specify `runtime: nvidia` on my laptop ?
Something that makes `docker --runtime=nvidia` equivalent to `docker --runtime=runc` ?

This would make me able to run containers designed for use with a GPU on my laptop.
Currently, `docker-compose` files that specify `runtime: nvidia` cause: `ERROR: for toto  Cannot create container for service toto: Unknown runtime specified nvidia`.

PS: I know this is janky but I need to test the containers, without rewriting `docker-compose.yaml` or having multiple docker-compose files if possible.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

For this, I needed to add a runtime called nvidia, [just like if I had an nvidia GPU](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/59008295/add-nvidia-runtime-to-docker-runtimes).
But since I don't have docker-nvidia-runtime, I need to redirect to `runc`:

```
$ find / -name runc 2>/dev/null
/usr/bin/runc
```

Final command:

```
$ sudo tee /etc/docker/daemon.json <<EOF
{
    "runtimes": {
        "nvidia": {
            "path": "/usr/bin/runc",
            "runtimeArgs": []
        }
    }
}
EOF
sudo pkill -SIGHUP dockerd
```