# Restart dockerd in Gitlab CI (docker-in-docker, dind)

Tags: docker, docker-compose, gitlab-ci, alpine-linux

I want to setup Gitlab CI/CD on my project which involves:

- 1 x `docker-compose.yml` for the whole project
- n x `Dockerfile` for each micro-services.

The thing is, I have one service that uses GPU computing with CUDA which means:

- One dockerfile uses: `FROM nvidia/cuda:10.1-devel-ubuntu18.04`
- The `docker-compose.yml` involves `runtime: nvidia` :

```
version: '3'
services:

  [other services...]

  my_service:
    runtime: nvidia
    build:
      context: ...
    environment:
      - ...
```

It works well on machines that have `nivida-docker`. However, I do not plan on using GPU during Gitlab CI so I looked for a workaround to keep the same `docker-compose.yml` but not raising error on `runtime: nvidia` and found [this `/etc/docker/daemon.json` trick to define a *fake* `nvidia` runtime that is actually `runc`](https://stackoverflow.com/a/65683280/5903959).

The trick actually works on my ubuntu machine i.e. I can see the *fake* runtime after `sudo service docker restart; docker info`

However I do not manage to restart docker so that it takes the new `daemon.json` into account.

I tried to start dockerd manually with `dockerd` but it errors, saying that `dockerd` isn't define. When I'm just commenting `runtime: nvidia` it all works like a charm which I dont understand how considering `dockerd` is missing?

Could you point out a wait to take `daemon.json` into account on gitlab-ci (alpine linux) ?

Answer (score 0):

As pointed in [the documentation](https://docs.gitlab.com/ee/ci/docker/using_docker_build.html#the-docker-executor-in-the-gitlab-runner-configuration-file), you can mount a *daemon.json* in every `dind` instances, using the *config.toml* configuration file.

They propose you yo host your custom *daemon.json* in */opt/docker/daemon.json*, this would be the one containing your `runc` runtime.

Then, you have to mount that in each container's */etc/docker/daemon.json*, in the *config.toml*:

```
[[runners]]
  ...
  executor = "docker"
  [runners.docker]
    image = "alpine:3.12"
    privileged = true
    volumes = ["/opt/docker/daemon.json:/etc/docker/daemon.json:ro"]
```

As for the location of this file:

> You can find the `config.toml` file in:
>
> - `/etc/gitlab-runner/` on *nix systems when GitLab Runner is executed as root (**this is also the path for service configuration**)
> - `~/.gitlab-runner/` on *nix systems when GitLab Runner is executed as non-root
> - `./` on other systems

*<sup>Source: https://docs.gitlab.com/runner/configuration/advanced-configuration.html</sup>*

Comment: Thanks for the answer thats informative! However, I suppose this is written for people that runs its own Gitlab Runner, right? When using Gitlab CI's runners I'm not sure where to write `config.toml`