# Add nvidia runtime to docker runtimes on windows WSL

Tags: docker, pytorch, windows-subsystem-for-linux, nvidia, wsl-2

I want to add the nvidia runtime to my docker.
Note that i am running windows 11.
Docker Desktop v.4.24.2 on Windows integrated on WSL 2
NVIDIA Drivers 545.84

I installed everything as nvidia-container-toolkit and  in the wsl that is running ubuntu 22.04 LTS
I am able to run

```
docker run --gpus all --ipc=host --ulimit memlock=-1 --ulimit stack=67108864 -it --rm -v .:/app nvcr.io/nvidia/pytorch:22.07-py3
```

And it actually loads my GPU with everything it needs. I know this because i am able to execute inside a jupyter notebook

```
import torch
for i in range(torch.cuda.device_count()):
   print(torch.cuda.get_device_properties(i).name)
```

And it shows my GPU (RTX 2080 SUPER)

But if i want to use the flag --runtime=nvidia it says

docker: Error response from daemon: unknown or invalid runtime name: nvidia.
See 'docker run --help'.

I want to use it inside a docker compose:

```
version: '3'
services:
  pytorch_container:
    image: nvcr.io/nvidia/pytorch:22.07-py3
    command: ["bash"]
    volumes:
      - .:/app
    runtime: nvidia
    ipc: host
    ulimits:
      memlock: -1
      stack: 67108864
    stdin_open: true
    tty: true
```

It doesnt run because it doesnt find the nvidia runtime

I already tried
https://stackoverflow.com/a/59008360/22768491
and still nothing

Comment: So i will answer my own question.
As i said, I already tried adding in the /etc/docker/daemon.json :
{
    "runtimes": {
        "nvidia": {
            "path": "/usr/bin/nvidia-container-runtime",
            "runtimeArgs": []
        }
    }
}

But it looks like the Docker desktop on windows doesnt look there. I found the daemon json in the Docker Desktop Settings under Docker Engine. I added the entry manually there and now it loads the nvidia runtime

I hope it helps someone else

Answer (score 12):

So i will answer my own question.

As i said, I already tried adding in the /etc/docker/daemon.json :

```
{
    "runtimes":{
        "nvidia":{
            "path":"/usr/bin/nvidia-container-runtime",
            "runtimeArgs":[
                
            ]
        }
    }
}
```

But it looks like the **Docker desktop on windows doesnt look there**.
I found the daemon json in the Docker Desktop **Settings under Docker Engine**.
I **added the entry manually** there and **now it loads the nvidia runtime** I hope it helps someone else

Comment: yes , win10 wsl2 works well

Comment: would that allow kubernetes for docker-desktop to run with gpu support?