# GPU support on Kubernetes of Docker for Desktop on Windows 11 with WSL 2

Tags: windows, kubernetes, gpu, wsl-2, docker-desktop

I am using the latest version of Docker Desktop with Kubernetes enabled on Windows 11 via WSL 2. My laptop has an NVidia GPU RTX 3080 ti.

The GPU is available for Docker out of the box (see listing below).

I want to make the GPU available to containers in the Kubernetes node.

1. Is that possible?
2. What are the steps to achieve that?

I already looked here:

- https://www.docker.com/blog/wsl-2-gpu-support-for-docker-desktop-on-nvidia-gpus/ (nothing related to Kubernetes)
- https://github.com/NVIDIA/k8s-device-plugin#quick-start (nothing specific for windows)
- https://docs.nvidia.com/datacenter/cloud-native/container-toolkit/latest/install-guide.html (nothing related to windows)
- https://docs.nvidia.com/cuda/wsl-user-guide/index.html (nothing related to Kubernetes)
- https://www.reddit.com/r/docker/comments/plqlp9/docker_desktop_wsl2_kubernetes_gpu_support/ (Similar question on reddit r/docker, no luck there)
- https://www.reddit.com/r/kubernetes/comments/pldgb6/wsl2_kubernetes_gpu_support/ (Similar question on reddit)
- https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=DmfuJzX6vJQ (screencast showing the installation of microk8s on windows 11 with wsl2, nothing on GPU... there is hope)
- https://microk8s.io/docs/install-wsl2 (microk8s on wsl2, nothing on enabling the GPU plugin... there is hope)
- https://developer.nvidia.com/blog/announcing-cuda-on-windows-subsystem-for-linux-2/ (nvidia support for wsl2, nothing on kubernetes)
- [Add nvidia runtime to docker runtimes on windows WSL](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/77323535/add-nvidia-runtime-to-docker-runtimes-on-windows-wsl) (how to enable nvidia-container-runtime for wsl2, nothing on Kubernetes, and this might break docker out of the box wsl2 support... there is hope)

However I could not find an answer or a how-to guide.

What is puzzling is that running Docker containers with --gpus all works out of the box, however kubernetes containers (that are visible in docker deskopt) do not seem to have gpu support. Maybe Docker Desktop starts them without --gpus all. Could it be that simple? Is there a way to check/change/configure kubernetes on docker desktop? A hidden .kubernetes file or something of the sort?

Below are some useful listings:

The output of running nvidia-smi in an ubuntu container on docker for desktop on windows 11 with WSL 2 with GPU support (out of the box):

```
$docker run --rm --gpus all -it ubuntu nvidia-smi
Wed Jan 24 17:58:46 2024
+---------------------------------------------------------------------------------------+
| NVIDIA-SMI 545.37.02              Driver Version: 546.65       CUDA Version: 12.3     |
|-----------------------------------------+----------------------+----------------------+
| GPU  Name                 Persistence-M | Bus-Id        Disp.A | Volatile Uncorr. ECC |
| Fan  Temp   Perf          Pwr:Usage/Cap |         Memory-Usage | GPU-Util  Compute M. |
|                                         |                      |               MIG M. |
|=========================================+======================+======================|
|   0  NVIDIA GeForce RTX 3080 ...    On  | 00000000:01:00.0 Off |                  N/A |
| N/A   61C    P8              12W / 150W |    635MiB / 16384MiB |      0%      Default |
|                                         |                      |                  N/A |
+-----------------------------------------+----------------------+----------------------+

+---------------------------------------------------------------------------------------+
| Processes:                                                                            |
|  GPU   GI   CI        PID   Type   Process name                            GPU Memory |
|        ID   ID                                                             Usage      |
|=======================================================================================|
|    0   N/A  N/A         1      C   /python3.7                                N/A      |
+---------------------------------------------------------------------------------------+
```

And kubectl describe node gives the following output: (note the missing GPU)

```
$ kubectl describe node
Name:               docker-desktop
Roles:              control-plane
Labels:             beta.kubernetes.io/arch=amd64
                    beta.kubernetes.io/os=linux
                    feature.node.kubernetes.io/cpu-cpuid.ADX=true
                    feature.node.kubernetes.io/cpu-cpuid.AESNI=true
                    feature.node.kubernetes.io/cpu-cpuid.AVX=true
                    feature.node.kubernetes.io/cpu-cpuid.AVX2=true
                    feature.node.kubernetes.io/cpu-cpuid.AVXVNNI=true
                    feature.node.kubernetes.io/cpu-cpuid.CETIBT=true
                    feature.node.kubernetes.io/cpu-cpuid.CETSS=true
                    feature.node.kubernetes.io/cpu-cpuid.CMPXCHG8=true
                    feature.node.kubernetes.io/cpu-cpuid.FLUSH_L1D=true
                    feature.node.kubernetes.io/cpu-cpuid.FMA3=true
                    feature.node.kubernetes.io/cpu-cpuid.FSRM=true
                    feature.node.kubernetes.io/cpu-cpuid.FXSR=true
                    feature.node.kubernetes.io/cpu-cpuid.FXSROPT=true
                    feature.node.kubernetes.io/cpu-cpuid.GFNI=true
                    feature.node.kubernetes.io/cpu-cpuid.HYPERVISOR=true
                    feature.node.kubernetes.io/cpu-cpuid.IA32_ARCH_CAP=true
                    feature.node.kubernetes.io/cpu-cpuid.IBPB=true
                    feature.node.kubernetes.io/cpu-cpuid.LAHF=true
                    feature.node.kubernetes.io/cpu-cpuid.MOVBE=true
                    feature.node.kubernetes.io/cpu-cpuid.MOVDIR64B=true
                    feature.node.kubernetes.io/cpu-cpuid.MOVDIRI=true
                    feature.node.kubernetes.io/cpu-cpuid.OSXSAVE=true
                    feature.node.kubernetes.io/cpu-cpuid.SERIALIZE=true
                    feature.node.kubernetes.io/cpu-cpuid.SHA=true
                    feature.node.kubernetes.io/cpu-cpuid.SPEC_CTRL_SSBD=true
                    feature.node.kubernetes.io/cpu-cpuid.STIBP=true
                    feature.node.kubernetes.io/cpu-cpuid.STOSB_SHORT=true
                    feature.node.kubernetes.io/cpu-cpuid.SYSCALL=true
                    feature.node.kubernetes.io/cpu-cpuid.SYSEE=true
                    feature.node.kubernetes.io/cpu-cpuid.VAES=true
                    feature.node.kubernetes.io/cpu-cpuid.VMX=true
                    feature.node.kubernetes.io/cpu-cpuid.VPCLMULQDQ=true
                    feature.node.kubernetes.io/cpu-cpuid.WAITPKG=true
                    feature.node.kubernetes.io/cpu-cpuid.X87=true
                    feature.node.kubernetes.io/cpu-cpuid.XGETBV1=true
                    feature.node.kubernetes.io/cpu-cpuid.XSAVE=true
                    feature.node.kubernetes.io/cpu-cpuid.XSAVEC=true
                    feature.node.kubernetes.io/cpu-cpuid.XSAVEOPT=true
                    feature.node.kubernetes.io/cpu-cpuid.XSAVES=true
                    feature.node.kubernetes.io/cpu-hardware_multithreading=true
                    feature.node.kubernetes.io/cpu-model.family=6
                    feature.node.kubernetes.io/cpu-model.id=151
                    feature.node.kubernetes.io/cpu-model.vendor_id=Intel
                    feature.node.kubernetes.io/kernel-config.NO_HZ_IDLE=true
                    feature.node.kubernetes.io/kernel-version.full=5.15.133.1-microsoft-standard-WSL2
                    feature.node.kubernetes.io/pci-0302_1414.present=true
                    feature.node.kubernetes.io/storage-nonrotationaldisk=true
                    kubernetes.io/arch=amd64
                    kubernetes.io/hostname=docker-desktop
                    kubernetes.io/os=linux
                    node-role.kubernetes.io/control-plane=
                    node.kubernetes.io/exclude-from-external-load-balancers=
Annotations:        kubeadm.alpha.kubernetes.io/cri-socket: unix:///var/run/cri-dockerd.sock
                    nfd.node.kubernetes.io/feature-labels:
                      cpu-cpuid.ADX,cpu-cpuid.AESNI,cpu-cpuid.AVX,cpu-cpuid.AVX2,cpu-cpuid.AVXVNNI,cpu-cpuid.CETIBT,cpu-cpuid.CETSS,cpu-cpuid.CMPXCHG8,cpu-cpuid...
                    node.alpha.kubernetes.io/ttl: 0
                    volumes.kubernetes.io/controller-managed-attach-detach: true
CreationTimestamp:  Fri, 19 Jan 2024 15:59:59 +0100
Taints:             <none>
Unschedulable:      false
Lease:
  HolderIdentity:  docker-desktop
  AcquireTime:     <unset>
  RenewTime:       Wed, 24 Jan 2024 19:01:25 +0100
Conditions:
  Type             Status  LastHeartbeatTime                 LastTransitionTime                Reason                       Message
  ----             ------  -----------------                 ------------------                ------                       -------
  MemoryPressure   False   Wed, 24 Jan 2024 19:01:27 +0100   Fri, 19 Jan 2024 15:59:58 +0100   KubeletHasSufficientMemory   kubelet has sufficient memory available
  DiskPressure     False   Wed, 24 Jan 2024 19:01:27 +0100   Fri, 19 Jan 2024 15:59:58 +0100   KubeletHasNoDiskPressure     kubelet has no disk pressure
  PIDPressure      False   Wed, 24 Jan 2024 19:01:27 +0100   Fri, 19 Jan 2024 15:59:58 +0100   KubeletHasSufficientPID      kubelet has sufficient PID available
  Ready            True    Wed, 24 Jan 2024 19:01:27 +0100   Fri, 19 Jan 2024 15:59:59 +0100   KubeletReady                 kubelet is posting ready status
Addresses:
  InternalIP:  192.168.65.3
  Hostname:    docker-desktop
Capacity:
  cpu:                24
  ephemeral-storage:  1055762868Ki
  hugepages-1Gi:      0
  hugepages-2Mi:      0
  memory:             16184860Ki
  pods:               110
Allocatable:
  cpu:                24
  ephemeral-storage:  972991057538
  hugepages-1Gi:      0
  hugepages-2Mi:      0
  memory:             16082460Ki
  pods:               110
System Info:
  Machine ID:                 8e4a9a84-8d9a-4100-8a35-25329f9bcd04
  System UUID:                8e4a9a84-8d9a-4100-8a35-25329f9bcd04
  Boot ID:                    cd21f4ff-4b7f-4ab0-9791-650f44921aab
  Kernel Version:             5.15.133.1-microsoft-standard-WSL2
  OS Image:                   Docker Desktop
  Operating System:           linux
  Architecture:               amd64
  Container Runtime Version:  docker://24.0.7
  Kubelet Version:            v1.28.2
  Kube-Proxy Version:         v1.28.2
Non-terminated Pods:          (21 in total)
  Namespace                   Name                                          CPU Requests  CPU Limits  Memory Requests  Memory Limits  Age
  ---------                   ----                                          ------------  ----------  ---------------  -------------  ---
  default                     ingress-nginx-controller-76df688779-vmgcm     100m (0%)     0 (0%)      90Mi (0%)        0 (0%)         5d2h
  kube-system                 coredns-5dd5756b68-267mg                      100m (0%)     0 (0%)      70Mi (0%)        170Mi (1%)     5d3h
  kube-system                 coredns-5dd5756b68-h8vlt                      100m (0%)     0 (0%)      70Mi (0%)        170Mi (1%)     5d3h
  kube-system                 etcd-docker-desktop                           100m (0%)     0 (0%)      100Mi (0%)       0 (0%)         5d3h
  kube-system                 kube-apiserver-docker-desktop                 250m (1%)     0 (0%)      0 (0%)           0 (0%)         5d3h
  kube-system                 kube-controller-manager-docker-desktop        200m (0%)     0 (0%)      0 (0%)           0 (0%)         5d3h
  kube-system                 kube-proxy-9v4pl                              0 (0%)        0 (0%)      0 (0%)           0 (0%)         5d3h
  kube-system                 kube-scheduler-docker-desktop                 100m (0%)     0 (0%)      0 (0%)           0 (0%)         5d3h
  kube-system                 nvidia-device-plugin-daemonset-wv575          0 (0%)        0 (0%)      0 (0%)           0 (0%)         17h
  kube-system                 storage-provisioner                           0 (0%)        0 (0%)      0 (0%)           0 (0%)         5d3h
  kube-system                 vpnkit-controller                             0 (0%)        0 (0%)      0 (0%)           0 (0%)         5d3h
  node-feature-discovery      nfd-gc-5b987cb58f-qxn64                       0 (0%)        0 (0%)      0 (0%)           0 (0%)         17h
  node-feature-discovery      nfd-master-7bff75887-vs825                    0 (0%)        0 (0%)      0 (0%)           0 (0%)         17h
  node-feature-discovery      nfd-worker-f8f9s                              0 (0%)        0 (0%)      0 (0%)           0 (0%)         17h
Allocated resources:
  (Total limits may be over 100 percent, i.e., overcommitted.)
  Resource           Requests    Limits
  --------           --------    ------
  cpu                950m (3%)   0 (0%)
  memory             330Mi (2%)  340Mi (2%)
  ephemeral-storage  0 (0%)      0 (0%)
  hugepages-1Gi      0 (0%)      0 (0%)
  hugepages-2Mi      0 (0%)      0 (0%)
Events:              <none>
```

and the output for kubectl describe daemonset nvidia-device-plugin-daemonset -n kuda-system:

```
$ kubectl describe daemonset nvidia-device-plugin-daemonset -n kuda-system:
Name:           nvidia-device-plugin-daemonset
Selector:       name=nvidia-device-plugin-ds
Node-Selector:  <none>
Labels:         <none>
Annotations:    deprecated.daemonset.template.generation: 1
Desired Number of Nodes Scheduled: 1
Current Number of Nodes Scheduled: 1
Number of Nodes Scheduled with Up-to-date Pods: 1
Number of Nodes Scheduled with Available Pods: 1
Number of Nodes Misscheduled: 0
Pods Status:  1 Running / 0 Waiting / 0 Succeeded / 0 Failed
Pod Template:
  Labels:  name=nvidia-device-plugin-ds
  Containers:
   nvidia-device-plugin-ctr:
    Image:      nvcr.io/nvidia/k8s-device-plugin:v0.14.3
    Port:       <none>
    Host Port:  <none>
    Environment:
      FAIL_ON_INIT_ERROR:  false
    Mounts:
      /var/lib/kubelet/device-plugins from device-plugin (rw)
  Volumes:
   device-plugin:
    Type:               HostPath (bare host directory volume)
    Path:               /var/lib/kubelet/device-plugins
    HostPathType:
  Priority Class Name:  system-node-critical
Events:                 <none>
```